# Why in zmq, I am using push and publish with two different sockets. I can push data to server but server is unable to publish back

Tags: sockets, push, zeromq, publish-subscribe

```
#include "string.h"
#include "assert.h"
#include "zhelpers.h"
#include "zmq.h"

int main (void)
{

   void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
   void *pushh   = zmq_socket  ( context, ZMQ_PUSH );          \*push socket*\    
   int   rc      = zmq_connect ( pushh, "tcp://localhost:5555" );
   assert (rc == 0);

   void *subscriber = zmq_socket  ( context, ZMQ_SUB );
   rc =               zmq_connect ( subscriber, "tcp://localhost:5557" );

   //                                          |0123456<NULL>|
   zmq_setsockopt ( subscriber, ZMQ_SUBSCRIBE, "10001 ", 6 );
   assert (rc == 0);

   char buffer[10];

   printf ("Enter. \n");
   scanf("%s", &buffer);

   zmq_send (pushh, buffer, 9, 0);    \\ send message by pushing to server

   sleep(1);
   zmq_recv (subscriber,buffer,10,0);

   printf ("Received= %s,.\n",buffer);    \*ready to be received message as subscriber`s`*\

   zmq_close (pushh);    
   zmq_ctx_destroy (context);

   return 0;

}
```

Comment: sorry for my bad code posting. I could not properly format. I am not familiar with the system. I tried hard but could not do.

Comment: Complete the code, ZMQ_PUBLISH socket is missing

Comment: This is client code. I have same code on server with pull and publish sockets. But thing is that it wont work out.assertion get failed on publisher when i try to run server side code :)

Comment: Complete the code. It is a fair practice on StackOverflow, the Community you ask to sponsor you to solve your problem to be responsive to suggestions on missing parts and to demonstrate your own effort to work on the subject matter. Telling stories about any code -- *instead of posting your code and showing your own work and efforts to test it* -- is a way to lose your own credit. So **it is much wiser to be carefull and a lot more cooperative on the way you ask other people to do the job for you.**